# How can I set reply mail address in navision 2016 mail

Tags: email, navision

I am using Nav 2016. Here I need to sent mail. But the reply address must be different from the sent address.

```
TempmailItem."Send to":=SendtoEmail;
TempmailItem.Subject:=MailsSubject;
TempmailItem."From Address":='xxxx@xxxxxx.xxx';
TempmailItem."From Name":='Test Mail';
TempmailItem."Plaintext Formatted":=FALSE;
TempmailItem.Send:=TRUE;  
TempmailItem.rep
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible because the reply address is not part of either Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.SMTP.SmtpMessage.'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.SMTP or Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Integration.Office.Outlook.IOutlookMessage

However if you're using O365 you can send an E-mail using Microsoft Graph, the replyTo Property is available for message : [developer.microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/message)

Cheers